# How can I pause the loop iteration based on specific condition?

Tags: jmeter

**Usecase :-** My test contains 3 Thread Group. Each Thread Group is having one loop controller with loop count 2 and all the HTTP requests inside it.I need to execute first loop iteration and pause the loop iteration then execute next thread loop's first iteration and pause until first loop iteration of all the Thread Group is completed. After completion of first iteration start second iteration of all the Thread Groups.

```
enter code here
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/#Inter-Thread-Communication), it provides possibility to share the variables across threads (and Thread Groups) via some form of a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) queue so you can use it as a "trigger" for the next iteration start in other thread groups.

Check out [How to Use the Inter-Thread Communication Plugin in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) article for more details.

Be aware that the Inter-Thread Communication Plugin is not a part of JMeter distribution bundle, you will have to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

[image]